# How can I have two slide-boxes at the same page?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to have and manipulate two sliders in the same page, how can I do it? Can I set some id for each one?

**controllers.js**

```
.controller('appCtrl', function($scope, $http, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate, methodsProvider, $ionicPopup) {
    methodsProvider.getTemas().then(function(data) {
      $scope.temas = data.temas[0].arquivosSinais;
    });

    $scope.confirm = function(x) {
      console.log($ionicSlideBoxDelegate.currentIndex());
    };

    $scope.previous = function() {
      $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.previous();
    };

    $scope.next = function() {
      $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.next();
    };
```

**index.html**

```
<ion-slide-box>
         <ion-slide ng-repeat="x in temas" ng-click="playVideo(x.arquivosSinalizacoes,x.id)">
              <img ng-src="{{x.imagemPreVisualizacao}}" alt="{{x.nome}}" />
         </ion-slide>
</ion-slide-box>
<!--   ----------------------------------------------------------------  -->
<ion-slide-box>
      <ion-slide ng-repeat="x in temas">
              <p>
                {{x.nome}}
             </p>
      </ion-slide>
</ion-slide-box>
```

The problem here is that when I use the first slide-box the second one is ignored and I loose it's values. What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working, from a help of [**wedgybo**](https://forum.ionicframework.com/users/wedgybo/activity) .

Here it is:

> Problem with 2 ion-slide-box on the same page You need to make use of
>   the delegate-handle attribute.
>
> `<ion-slide-box delegate-handle="slidebox1>`
>
> Then you can reference the slide-box like so
>
> `$ionicSlideBoxDelegate.$getByHandle('slidebox1').next();`